# Thumbnails wordpress em Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou usando o seguinte código para habilitar Custom Posts Types em meu site. No functions. O que devo adicionar a este código para que apareça a função de thumbnails ao post personalizado?

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'portfolio',
array(
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Porfolio' )
  ),
  'public' => true,
)
  );
}
register_taxonomy(
"categorias", 
  "portfolio", 
  array(            
    "label" => "Categorias", 
        "singular_label" => "Categoria", 
        "rewrite" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true
)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta que, no segundo parâmetro de [`register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), você adicione o seguinte:

```
'supports' => array( 'thumbnail ')
```

Como é possível ver na documentação, o *array* `supports` é onde você coloca tudo que o seu *custom post* vai suportar. Veja que, para que isso funcione, o seu tema deve estar com o suporte para *thumbnails* habilitado. Isso pode ser feito no arquivo `functions.php`, colocando

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Notei também que o seu código fonte não tem a *action* necessária para registrar a *custom taxonomy* ([como mostra a documentação](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)).  Então, supondo que voce ainda não a tenha registrado, e para que tudo funcione (e consertando alguns erros de indentação), o seu código deve ficar assim

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_taxonomy ');

function create_post_type() {

    register_post_type( 'portfolio', 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Porfolio' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'thumbnail ')
        )
    );
}

function register_custom_taxonomy(){

    register_taxonomy( 'categorias', 'portfolio', 
        array(
            'label' => 'Categorias', 
            'singular_label' => 'Categoria', 
            'rewrite' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
    );
}
```